# getting extra line of output in file

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm pretty new to C++, so bear with me. I am trying to write a program to read grades from a file and print the averaged grades plus a letter grade into a file. My input file has 3 lines of grades, so should only print 3 lines of grades. I am getting a fourth line of garbage, however, but I cannot figure out why. I've tried asking my teacher for assistance, but all he tells me is read the book, which doesn't cover this issue. Can someone please shed some light? I'm really sorry for so much code, but I'm not sure what might be relevant.

```
grades.txt
76 67 83 49 1111111 75 85 70 90
92 87 91 73 0110101 85 95 100 95
98 91 95 87 1111101 100 100 100 95


const int NUMHOMEWORK=7;
const int NUMPROGRAMS=4;
const float MAXPROGRAMS=400.0;
const char ASCIICONVERT=0x0f;

int main(){

int exam, test1, test2, test3, testTotal, hwGrade, progTemp, finalGrade;

char hwTemp, letterGrade;
ifstream inData;
ofstream outData;

inData.open("grades.txt");
if (!inData){
    cout<<"Cannot open the input file.";
    return 1;}

outData.open("finalgrades.txt");
if (!outData){
    cout<<"Cannot open the output file.";
    return 1;}

while (inData){

    int hwTotal=0;
    int progTotal=0;
    int i=0;    

    inData>>exam>>test1>>test2>>test3;

    if (test1<test2 && test1<test3)     
        testTotal=test2+test3;
    else if (test2<test1 && test2<test3)
        testTotal=test1+test3;
    else
        testTotal=test1+test2;

    do{                             
        inData.get(hwTemp);             
        hwGrade=hwTemp&ASCIICONVERT;    
        if (hwGrade==1)                 
            hwTotal=hwTotal+hwGrade;        
        i++;
    } while (i<=NUMHOMEWORK);

    i=0;                            
    do{
        inData>>progTemp;           
        progTotal=progTotal+progTemp;   
        i++;
    } while (i<NUMPROGRAMS);

    if (hwTotal==NUMHOMEWORK)           
        hwTotal--;

    exam=((exam/100.0)+0.005)*25;
    testTotal=((testTotal/200.0)+0.005)*40;
    hwTotal=((hwTotal/6.0)+0.005)*10;
    progTotal=((progTotal/MAXPROGRAMS)+0.005)*25;

    finalGrade=exam+testTotal+hwTotal+progTotal;

    if (90<=finalGrade)
        letterGrade='A';
    else if (80<=finalGrade<=89)
        letterGrade='B';
    else if (70<=finalGrade<=79)
        letterGrade='C';
    else if (60<=finalGrade<=69)
        letterGrade='D';
    else if (finalGrade<=59)
        letterGrade='F';

    outData<<exam<<" "<<testTotal<<" "<<hwTotal<<" "<<progTotal<<" "<<finalGrade<<" "<<letterGrade<<endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you paste the content of grades.txt?

Comment: `76 67 83 49 1111111 75 85 70 90` -- here space after `49` is getting read. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your i is 0-based index, and the following line:

```
while (i<=NUMHOMEWORK);
```

counts all the way to NUMHOMEWORK (inclusive), thus you end up having NUMHOMEWORK + 1 lines  - the last one is garbage.

Comment: I don't believe that part of the code is the issue, because I can take it out, and still get the extra line of garbage. But thank you for pointing it out for me. It solves a calculation error I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the grades.txt but this is what is probably happening:

Your `inData.get(hwTemp);` is reading the space that you have provided in the grades.txt after the value for `test3`.

One quick fix would be to read and ignore that space. For ex add following line before the first `do` statement:

`inData.get(hwTemp);`

This will read the space and ignore it.

Comment: +1 well spotted... @Maggie K you'll find these kinds of errors yourself if you put some `std::cout << "hwTemp is `" << hwTemp << "`\n";`-style trace statements throughout your code until you've convinced yourself it's working well....

Answer (score 0):

You should write...

```
while (inData >> exam >> test1 >> test2 >> test3)
   ...
```

...so the input loop only continues while actual input can be done.  Just knowing the file state's ok before attempting the input doesn't guarantee the input will be available.

Similarly, you should really check that the `inData.get()` and `inData >> progTemp` operations work (ala `if (!inData) { std::cerr << "bad input\n"; exit(1); }`) - or you may still get garbage for an invalid input file.

Comment: See, this `{ std::cerr << "bad input\n"; exit(1); }` is above my level at the moment. We haven't been taught any of that. And your suggestion for the while condition just gives me two lines of garbage instead of my 3 lines of correct numbers and 1 line of garbage.

Comment: `std::cerr` is like `std::cout`, but intended for error messages, and in general you shouldn't output messages without eventually adding a newline, as some terminals won't properly display the output (e.g. UNIX/Linux shells often return to the start of line to print their prompts, so unterminated lines may be overwritten before you read them).  `exit(1)` is the same as `return 1` when done from inside the `main()` function - it stops the program and hints to the OS/shell something went wrong (an exit code of 0 is used for success).

Comment: If "my" `while` is not working, then you've failed to replace your old version with mine properly, and/or have further/separate problems as Peter's answer suggests.  You might usefully edit your code append "UPDATED CODE: ..." - best not to replace your old code as it helps others understand your original question and existing answers.  You should also list your input file content.